# How to typehint numpy array of floats and/or integers

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm not sure how to go about typehinting the following:

```py
def prop(
    *,
    arr,  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
):
    return 100 * arr / arr.sum()
```

I've tried the following:

```py
def prop(
    *,
    arr: npt.NDArray[np._IntType] | npt.NDArray[np._FloatType],  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
) -> npt.NDArray[np._IntType] | npt.NDArray[np._FloatType]:
    return 100 * arr / arr.sum()
```

And am getting the errors from running `mypy <path>/check_mypy.py --strict`:

```
check_mypy.py:12: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Union[ndarray[Any, dtype[np._IntType]], ndarray[Any, dtype[np._FloatType]]]"  [no-any-return]
check_mypy.py:17: error: Need type annotation for "x"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:18: error: Need type annotation for "x1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:22: error: Need type annotation for "y"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:23: error: Need type annotation for "y1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:27: error: Need type annotation for "z"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:28: error: Need type annotation for "z1"  [var-annotated]
```

Full example:

```py
# check_mypy.py
from __future__ import annotations

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


def prop(
    *,
    arr: npt.NDArray[np._IntType] | npt.NDArray[np._FloatType],  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
) -> npt.NDArray[np._IntType] | npt.NDArray[np._FloatType]:
    return 100 * arr / arr.sum()


def main() -> int:
    # check 1 - ints
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    x1 = prop(arr=x)
    print(x1)

    # check 2 - mixed
    y = np.array([1.4, 21, 3.2])
    y1 = prop(arr=y)
    print(y1)

    # check 3 - floats
    z = np.array([1.4, 2.1, 3.2])
    z1 = prop(arr=z)
    print(z1)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

### edit 1

> If you do x: npt.NDArray[np._IntType] = np.array([1, 2, 3]) does that work?

Following the above I get the following error output:

```
check_mypy.py:12: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Union[ndarray[Any, dtype[np._IntType]], ndarray[Any, dtype[np._FloatType]]]"  [no-any-return]
check_mypy.py:17: error: Type variable "numpy._IntType" is unbound  [valid-type]
check_mypy.py:17: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[_IntType]" or "Protocol[_IntType]" base class to bind "_IntType" inside a class)
check_mypy.py:17: note: (Hint: Use "_IntType" in function signature to bind "_IntType" inside a function)
check_mypy.py:18: error: Need type annotation for "x1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:23: error: Need type annotation for "y"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:24: error: Need type annotation for "y1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:28: error: Need type annotation for "z"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:29: error: Need type annotation for "z1"  [var-annotated]
```

### edit 2.

After updating the function to:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', np._IntType, np._FloatType)


def prop(
    *,
    arr: npt.NDArray[T],  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
) -> npt.NDArray[T]:
    return 100 * arr / arr.sum()
```

I get the following error output:

```
check_mypy.py:15: error: Type variable "numpy._IntType" is unbound  [valid-type]
check_mypy.py:15: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[_IntType]" or "Protocol[_IntType]" base class to bind "_IntType" inside a class)
check_mypy.py:15: note: (Hint: Use "_IntType" in function signature to bind "_IntType" inside a function)
check_mypy.py:15: error: Type variable "numpy._FloatType" is unbound  [valid-type]
check_mypy.py:15: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[_FloatType]" or "Protocol[_FloatType]" base class to bind "_FloatType" inside a class)
check_mypy.py:15: note: (Hint: Use "_FloatType" in function signature to bind "_FloatType" inside a function)
check_mypy.py:22: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[np._IntType?]]"  [no-any-return]
check_mypy.py:22: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[np._FloatType?]]"  [no-any-return]
check_mypy.py:27: error: Type variable "numpy._IntType" is unbound  [valid-type]
check_mypy.py:27: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[_IntType]" or "Protocol[_IntType]" base class to bind "_IntType" inside a class)
check_mypy.py:27: note: (Hint: Use "_IntType" in function signature to bind "_IntType" inside a function)
check_mypy.py:33: error: Need type annotation for "y"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:38: error: Need type annotation for "z"  [var-annotated]
```

### edit 3

> If you actually want to allows mixed arrays, then you can drop the type variable and use npt.NDArray[ np._IntType | np._FloatType ] in both cases

Updating the function to:

```py
def prop(
    *,
    arr: npt.NDArray[np._IntType | np._FloatType],  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
) -> npt.NDArray[np._IntType | np._FloatType]:
    return 100 * arr / arr.sum()
```

Gives the following errors:

```
check_mypy.py:22: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[Union[np._IntType, np._FloatType]]]"  [no-any-return]
check_mypy.py:27: error: Type variable "numpy._IntType" is unbound  [valid-type]
check_mypy.py:27: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[_IntType]" or "Protocol[_IntType]" base class to bind "_IntType" inside a class)
check_mypy.py:27: note: (Hint: Use "_IntType" in function signature to bind "_IntType" inside a function)
check_mypy.py:30: error: Need type annotation for "x1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:35: error: Need type annotation for "y"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:36: error: Need type annotation for "y1"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:40: error: Need type annotation for "z"  [var-annotated]
check_mypy.py:41: error: Need type annotation for "z1"  [var-annotated]
```

Comment: To me your type annotation looks good, not sure though if mypy can determine the right type of your arrays, seems like it can't. If you do x: npt.NDArray[np._IntType] = np.array([1, 2, 3]) does that work?

Comment: @SimonHawe i wasn't sure how to note that they could be _both_ int and float, rather than one or the other - i'll try your suggestion now, thanks

Comment: @SimonHawe just tried (edited post) - didn't seem to work.

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be npt.NDArray[np._FloatType]?

Comment: @SimonHawe maybe - i've tried to update with other suggestions and they're also failing mypy checks : (

Answer (score 3):

I was really curious to see how that could go. The best I was able to get is the following

```py
# check_mypy.py
from __future__ import annotations

# Third party
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
from typing import cast


def prop(
    *,
    arr: npt.NDArray[np.float64] | npt.NDArray[np.int64] ,  # numpy array of floats or/and ints
) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    return cast(npt.NDArray[np.float64], 100 * arr / arr.sum())


def main() -> int:
    # check 1 - ints
    x : npt.NDArray[np.float64] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    x1 = prop(arr=x)
    print(x1)

    # check 2 - mixed
    y : npt.NDArray[np.float64]  = np.array([1.4, 21, 3.2])
    y1 = prop(arr=y)
    print(y1)

    # check 3 - floats
    z: npt.NDArray[np.int64] = np.array([1.4, 2.1, 3.2])
    z1 = prop(arr=z)
    print(z1)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

So no mixed types as this doesn't make sense. Numpy arrays are always of a single type, even though you add other types when defining the array.

Using np.float64/np.int64 was actually what made it work in the end. Not sure if that is acceptable for you. Here you might want to define a Union or type var of all floats, but again not sure. Import thing is that it is a subclass of NP.generic.

Type annotating all defined arrays was also needed as mypy cannot determine the type on its own.

Last, returning fixed npt.NDArray[np.float64] as what you are computing there is always of that type.